# как посчитать с помощью SQL кол-во повторений значения в столбце?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, база-данных, postgresql

В SQL есть таблица **students:

-student_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,

-student_name VARCHAR,

-group_id INTEGER**
Мне в программе Java нужно получить Map<Integer, Integer>, где key -> group_id, а value -> кол-во студентов с этим group_id, то есть, кол-во повторений каждого group_id. Как составить для этого SQL запрос?

Comment: Обычный GROUP BY + COUNT(). Обычно рассказывается на 5-6 странице любой книжки про базы данных.

Comment: В программе Java можно группы поместить в мапу.

Comment: У меня задача перенести логику поиска, подсчета и фильтрации в SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне удалось собрать подходящий запрос, который идеально решает мою проблему.

`SELECT group_id, Count(student_id) FROM students WHERE group_id>0 GROUP BY students.group_id HAVING COUNT (student_id)<(?) ORDER BY students.group_id;`